# Generating XSD for serialized XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Currently, I have an xml file that looks like this...

```
<ArrayOfService>
    <Service>
        <Name>
            Something
        </Name>
        <Id>
            8003
        </Id>
    </Service>
</ArrayOfService>
```

This is automatically generated from a class that looks like this...

```
public class Service{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;

    public Service(){
    }
}
```

To turn the class into XML, I use...

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer( typeof(Service) );
xs.Serialize( context.Response.OutputStream, FunctionReturnsTypeService() );
```

Is there any way to also automatically generate an XSD like this?

EDIT:

Also, is there any way to add this schema to the xml as I'm serializing it?

Comment: what do you mean "add this schema to the XML"?  What do you want the output to look like, to contain?

Comment: I want the generated xml to have something like this at the top:

<ArrayOfService xmlns="http://tempuri/ArrayOfService.xsd">

Comment: xmlns="foo" indicates a namespace, not a schema.  If you want a specific xml namespace to be used when serializing a type, then you can use [XmlType(Namespace="Foo")] as an attribute on the type.

Comment: I think what you may want is xsi:schemaLocation, in which case, see here: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.xml/2006-12/msg00040.html

Comment: Add that link to your answer, I'll accept it. Looks like what i needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xsd.exe tool (%netsdk20%\bin\xsd.exe) infers a type from an XML document.

(You can also use the /c option to generate classes from an xml doc or schema.)

If you want to embed a reference to a schema into an XML doc, then see here:
http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/DotNet/microsoft.public.dotnet.xml/2006-12/msg00040.html

Summary:
decorate a member of your type with the XmlAttribute attribute, specifying "schemaLocation" as the name of the attr, and "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" as the namespace for that attribute.  As this example in C#

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute("schemaLocation",
    Namespace = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
private string xsiSchemaLocation = "YourSchema.xsd";
```

Comment: the XSD tool works, but not the /c option (that's for generating classes). I just typed xsd myfile.xml and it generated the schema. Awesome. Now, for the second part of my question.. :D

Comment: For on the fly schema generation,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336988/xml-serialization-and-schema-without-xsd-exe

Comment: The field xsiSchemaLocation needs to be public.