# Programmatically use XSD.exe tool feature (generate schema from class) through .NET Framework classes?

Tags: .net, xsd.exe, fcl

I want to generate an XML Schema based upon a class, just as you can
do with the [Xsd.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx).

E.g. `xsd.exe /type: typename /outputdir:c:\ assmeblyname`.

Is there a way to do this **by using classes in the .NET Framework** instead of using the standalone tool?

I'm sure I've seen information about task references or similar - i.e. something programmatic -  that can be used in place of some of these standalone utilities, or that some standalone  utilities get their features through the FCL or a Microsoft API.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of (as a one-shot class with a `GenerateXsd()` method).  But you can with a decent amount of elbow grease recreate it with a number of classes from System.Reflection and System.Xml.

Comment: Hmmmmm ... thanks JesseC.  Does anybody know of some of this prepackaged elbow grease on the Internet?

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but you could wrap the tool.  If it is a .NET tool, you could also reference the exe, and co-opt the code.

Comment: Google shows this: http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread80993.html.  Might be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Found this which looks like it should do the trick...

```
public static string GetSchema<T>()
    {
        XmlAttributeOverrides xao = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        AttachXmlAttributes(xao, typeof(T));

        XmlReflectionImporter importer = new XmlReflectionImporter(xao);
        XmlSchemas schemas = new XmlSchemas();
        XmlSchemaExporter exporter = new XmlSchemaExporter(schemas);
        XmlTypeMapping map = importer.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(T));
        exporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            schemas[0].Write(ms);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Full code at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336988/xml-serialization-and-schema-without-xsd-exe

Answer (score 1):

do this:

```
public string GetFullSchema() {

        string @namespace = "yourNamespace";

        var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
        where t.IsClass && t.Namespace ==  @namespace
        select t;

        XmlReflectionImporter importer = new XmlReflectionImporter(@namespace);

        XmlSchemas schemas = new XmlSchemas();
        XmlSchemaExporter exporter = new XmlSchemaExporter(schemas);


        foreach (var x in q)
        {
                var map = importer.ImportTypeMapping(x);
                exporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);
        }

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
           schemas[0].Write(ms);
           ms.Position = 0;
           return new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
        }

}
```