# Programmatically use XSD.exe tool feature (generate class from XSD Schema) through .NET Framework classes?

Tags: .net, xsd.exe, fcl

I want to generate a class from an XML XSD Schema, just as you can do with the [Xsd.exe tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(VS.80).aspx).

E.g. `XSD.exe /namespace:Generated.Xsd_1 /classes /outputdir:..\Classes`

Is there a way to do this **by using classes in the .NET Framework** instead of using the standalone tool?

Comment: @slugster: Yes, because it's a different question - reverse situation of the first.  The XSD tool goes two ways - requires a different solution for each.  NOTE TO EVERYBODY: NOT A DUPLICATE OF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150002/ Please read carefully!

Comment: mmmmkay, my bad. With a quick skim read this question appeared to be a cut down version of the alleged dupe.

Answer (score 11):

Shamelessly borrowed from [here](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2007/01/writing-your-own-xsdexe.html):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

using Microsoft.CSharp;

using NUnit.Framework;

namespace XmlSchemaImporterTest
{
  [TestFixture]
  public class XsdToClassTests
  {
      // Test for XmlSchemaImporter
      [Test]
      public void XsdToClassTest()
      {
          // identify the path to the xsd
          string xsdFileName = "Account.xsd";
          string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
          string xsdPath = Path.Combine(path, xsdFileName);

          // load the xsd
          XmlSchema xsd;
          using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(xsdPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
          {
              xsd = XmlSchema.Read(stream, null);
          }
          Console.WriteLine("xsd.IsCompiled {0}", xsd.IsCompiled);

          XmlSchemas xsds = new XmlSchemas();
          xsds.Add(xsd);
          xsds.Compile(null, true);
          XmlSchemaImporter schemaImporter = new XmlSchemaImporter(xsds);

          // create the codedom
          CodeNamespace codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace("Generated");
          XmlCodeExporter codeExporter = new XmlCodeExporter(codeNamespace);

          List maps = new List();
          foreach(XmlSchemaType schemaType in xsd.SchemaTypes.Values)
          {
              maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportSchemaType(schemaType.QualifiedName));
          }
          foreach(XmlSchemaElement schemaElement in xsd.Elements.Values)
          {
              maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportTypeMapping(schemaElement.QualifiedName));
          }
          foreach(XmlTypeMapping map in maps)
          {
              codeExporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);
          }

          RemoveAttributes(codeNamespace);

          // Check for invalid characters in identifiers
          CodeGenerator.ValidateIdentifiers(codeNamespace);

          // output the C# code
          CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();

          using(StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
          {
              codeProvider.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(codeNamespace, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
              Console.WriteLine(writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString());
          }

          Console.ReadLine();
      }

      // Remove all the attributes from each type in the CodeNamespace, except
      // System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute
      private void RemoveAttributes(CodeNamespace codeNamespace)
      {
          foreach(CodeTypeDeclaration codeType in codeNamespace.Types)
          {
              CodeAttributeDeclaration xmlTypeAttribute = null;
              foreach(CodeAttributeDeclaration codeAttribute in codeType.CustomAttributes)
              {
                  Console.WriteLine(codeAttribute.Name);
                  if(codeAttribute.Name == "System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute")
                  {
                      xmlTypeAttribute = codeAttribute;
                  }
              }
              codeType.CustomAttributes.Clear();
              if(xmlTypeAttribute != null)
              {
                  codeType.CustomAttributes.Add(xmlTypeAttribute);
              }
          }
      }
  }
}
```