# XSD.EXE to generate F# Classes off of XSD

Tags: f#, xsd.exe

I am trying to use the tool XSD.EXE to generate some class files from an XSD. Whether there is anything to be gained from the resulting files is another question, but I would like to see what is generated.  I found this [reference](http://mdavey.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/f-and-xsd-exe/), which notes:

> Which, thanks to Luke over on the F#
>   Visual Studio team, means I can do
>   this:

```
xsd.exe fpml-asset-4-z.xsd /classes /l:”Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider, FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom, Version=1.9.9.9, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809″
```

Which is splendid.  I don't have the same version of the code dom - so looking at the GAC I changed the line to:

```
xsd.exe RIXML-datatypes-2_3_1.xsd /classes /l:"Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider, FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom, Version=2.0.0,0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809"
```

Which yields:

> C:\Users\Desktop\CSharpSamples\ResearchUploader\Fc-RixmlLib>xsd.exe
>   RIXML-datatypes-2_3_1.xsd /classes
>   /l:"Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodePr
>   ovider, FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom,
>   Version=2.0.0,0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809"
>   Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes
>   support utility [Microsoft (R) .NET
>   Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
>   All rights reserved. Error: The given
>   assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
>
> If you would like more help, please
>   type "xsd /?".

Thoughts?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks correct to me. Can you double check that the assembly is installed in GAC?
Here is a command that you can enter to "Visual Studio Command Prompt":

```
> gacutil -l | find "FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom"
```

I got:

```
FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=a19089b1c74d0809, processorArchitecture=MSIL
```

Comment: Y - that seemed to generate the same thing. I tried to generate to C# and XSD.exe gave me a different error - that the schema lacked a top level element. I wouldn't be suprised if the error didn't bubble up correctly under f#, but somehow in this case - i don't believe this to be what caused my original error.

Comment: Having the same issue here - double-checked that the assembly exists in the GAC.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047" - did not manage to solve it but there is an ugly workaround:

1. Create a new C# console application
2. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150164/programmatically-use-xsd-exe-tool-feature-generate-class-from-xsd-schema-throu) for how to programatically do the same thing as xsd.exe
3. Add reference to your F# powerpack's CodeDom dll
4. Use Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom.FSharpCodeProvider instead of CSharpCodeProvider

Spent an hour trying to get xsd.exe to work, and it took me only 5 mins to bruteforce it this way..

This could be easily made into xsdfs.exe or something to save people the trouble of making xsd.exe to use the f# code dom :)

Answer (score 0):

Leave off the `Microsoft` part, and after you installed to GAC, it should work. They changed names a while back.

I can, after installing (disassemble and assemble - ildasm, gacutil fun) use both `xsd.exe` and the in-editor C# method (rewriting to F#). Thanks :)