# XSD tool appends "Specified" to certain properties/fields when generating C# code

Tags: c#, code-generation, xsd.exe

I got a strange behaviour with the XSD generator I can't really explain. I got an XSD like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="StageSequenceElement" mixed="false">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="CoreObject">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>Some Doc</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="StageRef" type="ObjectReference">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>...</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="MinDuration_100ms" type="xs:int" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>...</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="MaxDuration_100ms" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>...</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="StageOnDemand" type="xs:boolean" nillable="true" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:documentation>...</xs:documentation>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

it is derived from CoreObject:

```
<xs:complexType name="CoreObject">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="No" type="xs:int">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>...</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is just a small part of the XSD, there are a lot more complex types.

So when I generate the classes similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150164/programmatically-use-xsd-exe-tool-feature-generate-class-from-xsd-schema-throu), I get a generated class which has two more properties (in addition to the 5 which I would expect):

```
public bool MinDuration_100msSpecified
```

and

```
public bool StageOnDemandSpecified
```

So to the "original" property "Specified" was appended and the type is now bool.
Can anyone explain why this is so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the `bool` attribute means the related attribute should be serialized.

**e.g.**

If the `bool` `MinDuration_100msSpecified` is set to `false`, and you set the `MinDuration_100ms` to be `300`, when you use `XmlSerializer` to serialize the object, the `MinDuration_100ms` attribute won't be serialized.

This feature can save the serialized xml file to be minimal.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to prevent the creation of that property though?

Comment: You can try the xsd2code tools, which providing more functions. http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/

Comment: Well we ended up with a codegen by ourselfs which fits our needs, but thanks anyway :-)

Comment: @derape - I have a similar requirement as you had. Would it possible for you to share the code generator that you used?

Comment: @vivekp Our generator is designed to fit our specific needs (external dependencies etc.). So it would not make sense to do so. Also its companies property. But if you want to, I could give you directions if you need help creating your own...

Comment: @derape - Yes that makes sense. Thanks a lot. Here's my question which talks about my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599268/in-c-sharp-how-do-i-ignore-all-the-attributes-with-the-postfix-specified-gener

The question is simple. Is there a way not to have properties with "Specified" Postfix at all using xsd.exe or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Set **minOccurs="1"** where element is nillable.
For example:

```
<xs:element name="StageOnDemand" type="xs:boolean" nillable="true" minOccurs="1" />
```

Comment: That would change the semantical meaning which we did not want: `null` and empty is not the same...