# How to approach writing an F# type provider that enforces complex schema?

Tags: .net, f#, xsd, type-providers

Just recently I worked with some data for traffic and travel information, that is data in [Datex2](http://www.datex2.eu/content/datex-ii-xml-schema-21) format. The project wasn't long and is over now, and I went on as usually and generated a bunch of strongly typed C# classes with [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tool, did some serializing, light processing and so forth. However, now in hindsight I became to wonder if this would have been a good case for an F# type provider and so to take my first stab on this subject.

With this in mind, how should one approach a situation where there's a [complex schema](http://www.datex2.eu/archived-document/35) that shouldn't change often? As there isn't a publicly available type provider that would infer types from a schema directly, I guess the options are to:

- Use the [XML type provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html).
- Generate the types with and external tool, [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this case -- taking a cue from the [WSDL type provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh362328.aspx) (which uses [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
- Roll the types by hand (possibly modifying the output of [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
- Generate the types (as in previous bullet)/use the XML Type provider and do constant serializing, deserializing and schema validation in the background.

Then I also started to wonder about the C#-F# story (e.g. generated or erased types) and what if I wanted to modify the types to better check constraints like `<xs:element name="ilc" type="D2LogicalModel:TpegIlcPointDescriptor" maxOccurs="3">` in the schema whilst also providing a good developer experience.

Rolling one's own types looks like a rather laborius endavour and the the two last points seemed being the most appealing ones, so taking the route as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150164/programmatically-use-xsd-exe-tool-feature-generate-class-from-xsd-schema-throu) by [nos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126769/nos) in another SO post. I used `System.Xml` and `System.CodeDom` and modified the code to use `Microsoft.FSharp.Compiler.CodeDom` and `FSharpCodeProvider` to generate the F# types.

Alas! The generated F# code doesn't compile (even after adding the appropriate referecenses etc.) At this point I thought I could ask some directions.

**Question:** Is there a recommened, experience backed way to create a type provider to conform to a somewhat complex XML schema (taking Datex2 as a case example) if I would like to enforce constraints as described in a given schema as early as possible in the development cycle?

**<edit 2013-12-10:** [Rune FS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112407/rune-fs) is attempting to take a stab on this, see his SO question [Getting compile error on provided type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466880/getting-compile-error-on-provided-type).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a pretty complex question and I guess there is no simple answer - I think you probably enumerated all the options and also most of their trade-offs. For one-off projects, it does not really make sense to build a specific type provider for just a single purpose, so I think using XML provider or code generation are the only choices. Code generation (when modifying the generated code) is a maintenance nightmare.

As for the XML type provider, we have a [work item](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues/57) to add support for XSD (this would be nice community contribution as it is quite stand-alone), so if we had that, then I believe using the XML type provider would be perfect, because you could just pass it the DATEX II schema.

At the moment, F# Data uses erased types (bad for C# interop) but we are actually considering switching to generated types, which would make the provider usable from C# (via small F# project) - so, I think the type providers are the answer here, but they might need a few improvements before they're perfect for your project (but then, F# Data is an open source project and we always welcome contributions :-)).

Comment: Yes, the issue seems to be rather complicated. Originally I had hoped I could just (de)serialize XML fragments and use ``System.Xml.Schema`` for checking, but, nah, it looks like there will be too troublesome edge cases there... Anyhow, I'm not certainly able to lead this task, I'm a rather newbie F# guy. At most I can babble opinions from the sidewalk (yeah, talk is cheap :)) and help in testing and something "easy" someone can point out. Thanks for the GitHub pointer, I'll keep an eye on that if I could be of help in the future!