# xsd.exe generate only one class file

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I use command for NetFX 4.5.1 Tools from Microsoft SDK:

```
xsd schema.xsd /c
```

It generates only one class which have all the structure (schema.cs). But i need set of classes which structure described in schema.xsd. For example: Application.cs, Applicant.cs and so on, like I have after JAXB classes generating in Eclipse.

Here is part of schema.xsd code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2011 rel. 2 -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="3.0.0">
    <!-- Application -->
    <xs:element name="Application">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Заявка</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="DecisionResponse" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="CreditRequest" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element ref="Applicant"/>
                <xs:element ref="Routing"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute ref="applicationDate" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute ref="timestamp" use="optional"/>
            <xs:attribute name="applicationId" type="xs:int" use="optional">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>ID заявки</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="applicationDecision" type="xs:string" use="optional">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Итоговое решение по заявке</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <!-- DecisionResponse -->
    <xs:element name="DecisionResponse">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Решения по заявке</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Product" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```

Comment: Have a look at Xsd2Code as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best and simple option is to use WSCF blue , it's an add-in to Visual studio
just select your set of XSD files/WSDL and generate classes , then you have the option between multiple/single files and there you go

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `xsd.exe` has that option.

From my experience with `xsd.exe`, it's a great tool to get you going, but shouldn't be used like the T4 templates (e.g. .tt files for EF), but only be run once.

I've found that there are a bunch of `Attribute`s generated that you don't need and clutter the classes.

So IMHO it's best to simply:

- Sift through the generated `schema.cs` file
- Moving sub classes that were created (e.g. Application) into new files manually
- Remove unwanted `Attribute`s
- And lastly, format and rename the classes to make them maintainable for yourself (and whoever else needs to work on it)

This obviously might works best with a small or mid-sized schema.

Comment: 31 classes... and if there will be much more than 31 classes?)

Answer (score 0):

**No**. `xsd.exe` does not have an option to generate multiple classes from one xsd file.

You can try to do it programatically (See this example from [Mike Hadlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150164/programmatically-use-xsd-exe-tool-feature-generate-class-from-xsd-schema-throu))