# What is the meaning of "string @namespace" in C#?

Tags: c#

I came across some code (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4150264/6134962)) and I can't seem to figure out what I'm supposed to do with it. `@namespace` appears three times in the code. Here's what I'm looking at.

```
 public string GetFullSchema()
 {

     string @namespace = "yourNamespace";

     var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
             where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == @namespace
             select t;

     XmlReflectionImporter importer = new XmlReflectionImporter(@namespace);

     XmlSchemas schemas = new XmlSchemas();
     XmlSchemaExporter exporter = new XmlSchemaExporter(schemas);


    foreach (var x in q)
     {
         var map = importer.ImportTypeMapping(x);
         exporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);
     }

     using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
     {
         schemas[0].Write(ms);
         ms.Position = 0;
         return new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
     }

 }
```

Am I assuming correctly this is some sort of coding convention I'm unaware of? Should that line be replaced by something?

Comment: That one really didn't come up and I tried finding something similar to my case. But thanks, that really solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@`-symbol as an prefix allows you to use reserved keywords as variables again. The keyword `namespace` e.g. is already reserved by the language itself.
But in my oppinion this is not the common way to solve the problem. It is a better approach to rename the variable so that there is no conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The @ symbol will allow you to use reserved word. So whenever you want to use(*which you may try to avoid*) the identifier or keywords in your variable then you need to put the @ symbol next to it.

MSDN says:

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is
>   useful when interfacing with other programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `namespace` is a reserved word in C#. If you want to have an identifier in your code that matches some reserved word, you have to change the identifier. You can use underscore and sometimes people use `@`. Like `_namespace` or `@event`.

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670.aspx

> The prefix "@" enables the use of keywords as identifiers, which is useful when interfacing with other programming languages. The character @ is not actually part of the identifier, so the identifier might be seen in other languages as a normal identifier, without the prefix. An identifier with an @ prefix is called a verbatim identifier. Use of the @ prefix for identifiers that are not keywords is permitted, but strongly discouraged as a matter of style.