# Serialise to XML and XSD with Schema Location Results in Invalid XSD.

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

I am using .NET 3.5 to serialise a class to Xml and to create an XSD schema. The generated XML references the XSD using the schema location attribute.

My solution is based on these answers:
[XmlSerialization and xsi:SchemaLocation (xsd.exe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408336/xmlserialization-and-xsischemalocation-xsd-exe/1408387#1408387) and
[XML Serialization and Schema without xsd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336988/xml-serialization-and-schema-without-xsd-exe/338100#338100)

I add an attribute to my class to reference the XSD:

```
[XmlAttribute("schemaLocation", Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
public string XsiSchemaLocation = "MyNameSpace " + "MyNameSpace.xsd";
```

The problem is that the field XsiSchemaLocation ends up in my XSD file:

```
<xs:attribute xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ref="q1:schemaLocation" />
```

When I try to edit my serialised XML file auto-complete in Visual Studio doesn't work because of the above attribute and gives the below error:

> The 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance:schemaLocation' attribute is not declared.

My current solution to remove the schema location attribute from the XSD is the below hack:

```
    XmlReflectionImporter importer = new XmlReflectionImporter();
    XmlSchemas schemas = new XmlSchemas();
    XmlSchemaExporter exporter = new XmlSchemaExporter(schemas);
    XmlTypeMapping map = importer.ImportTypeMapping(m_SerializedType);
    exporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);
    using (var tw = new StreamWriter(m_XsdPath))
    {
        //Hack to remove the schema location from the XSD.
        ((System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaComplexType)(schemas[0].Items[1])).Attributes.Clear();
        schemas[0].Write(tw);
    }
```

Is there a better way than forcibly removing the attribute. Something like an [XmlSchemaIgnore] attribute would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

XML Serialization is meant to serialize your data. If the `schemaLocation` is part of your data, then you want it in your schema. If it's not in your data, then you shouldn't be serializing it.

Remember that `schemaLocation` is only a hint for tools that want to refer to the schema. It's not necessary in many cases (Visual Studio, for example).

Comment: When I serialise my data schemaLocation correctly appears in the XML file as xsi:schemaLocation="MyNameSpace MyNameSpace.xsd".

The problem is that schemaLocation should not be considered part of my XSD schema, it should be part of the imported schema (via XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace).

I want intellisense to work in Visual Studio if someone is editing my serialised data, without schemaLocation intellisense does not work, so it is necessary in my case.

Comment: You're mistaken. Intellisense will work if the schema file is in the same project, or if you "manually" set the schema to use. Again, you can't have it both ways.

Comment: These files don't exist in a project so Intellisense doesn't work without schema location. I want configuration engineers to open this file on a remote server in Visual Studio and edit it, it is troublesome if they have to manually select the schema. The answers I linked to say that my usage of schema location is correct for serialisation, so it is unfortunate that it doesn't seem to work for XSD generation.

Comment: Those answers were hacks that only "work" if you don't also need the schema. If you're down for creating your own subclass of `XmlWriter`, then you could override the generation of the root element to include the `schemaLocation` attribute.